# Is it frowned upon to accept answers in bulk?

Tags: support

I usually wait a week to accept an answer on any of my questions-- and by that I mean I always forget to go back and accept answers on all of my questions. I just went to like 10-20 of my questions and popped the green-check on nearly 20 at the same time.

**Other than spamming @OrganicMarble, @RusselBorogove and @uhoh (I think I accepted 3-4 from each of them) is there any downside to bulk-accepting old answers to questions?**

Comment: I honestly can't think of any problem with this. I suppose in the unlikely event you accepted a high proportion of a single user's answers at once it might appear to be some kind of reputation shenanigans, but I don't think that's really going to be an issue.

Comment: @called2voyage that was what I was worried about, I saw what occurred with another user (who I will not name). Honestly, I could give a flying fig about fake points-- but like to give users theirs in-case they like 'em.

Comment: Can any of the mods tell us: Can this trigger an automatic "voting reversal"?

Comment: @DrSheldon The exact details of those algorithms are opaque by design, but I have never seen acceptance reversed programmatically.

Comment: I am pretty certain this is fine - that usage pattern matches how various folks do it. They'll see a number of unaccepted ones on their profile page, and go in to sort that out, especially if they are intermittent visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something similar a few times and wondered similar things each time. I haven't seen any complaints. Since there are both [active] and [newest] listings available, it's easy for people to ignore a block of accepted answers.

[image: active and newest]

Over the centuries SE has evolved to be pretty robust.

A similar thing happens when there is a manual tag-adjustment on a group of questions. For example just now:

[image]